# Tooltip on each data point in Chartjs

Tags: chart.js

Here is my code for putting different tooltip on each data point.  I want to put different month on each point, but all the months get printed together.  How do I separate them out?

```js
function trendsChart(labels1, datasets1, chartId) {
  var ctx =
    document.getElementById(chartId).getContext('2d');
  var MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"];
  console.log(datasets1)
  var data = {
    labels: labels1,
    datasets: datasets1,
  };

  // Tooltip
  const titleTooltip = (tooltipItems) => {
    let sum = 77;
    MONTHS.forEach(function(tooltipItem) {
      sum = tooltipItem;
    })
    return sum;
  }

  var randomScalingFactor = function() {
    return (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1.0 : 1.0) * Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  };

  var line1 = [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()];

  myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        x: {
          barPercentage: 1.6,
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
            color: 'rgba(225,78,202,0.1)',
            zeroLineColor: "transparent",
          },
          ticks: {
            padding: 0,
            fontColor: "#9a9a9a"
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Week Of'
          }
        },
        y: {
          barPercentage: 1.6,
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
            color: 'rgba(225,78,202,0.1)',
            zeroLineColor: "transparent",
          },
          ticks: {
            padding: 0,
            fontColor: "#9a9a9a"
          },
          stacked: false,
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Count'
          }
        }
      },
      plugins: {
        tooltip: {
          //yAlign: 'bottom',
          callbacks: {
            title: titleTooltip,
          }
        }
      }
    }

  });

  return myChart;

}
```

[image: Adding different tooltip for each data point]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `titleTooltip` in the pasted code, you replace `sum` with the last entry from `MONTHS`. The tooltip from the image however suggests that in the real code, you create an array with `77` and all entries from `MONTHS`, then you probably return `'Sum: ' + sum`, which results in the string you can see in the tooltip.

In order to see all the months on a separate line, you could change your code as follows and return `sum` as an `array`:

```
const titleTooltip = ctx => {
  let sum = ['Sum: 77'];
  MONTHS.forEach(month => {
    sum.push(month);
  });    
  return sum;
}
```

> The resulting tooltip still doesn't make much sense but you'll see all months on a different line. Therefore, you to extend the function `titleTooltip` in order to obtain the desired result.

Please take a loo at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
function trendsChart(labels1, datasets1, chartId) {
  var MONTHS = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June"];
  var data = {
    labels: labels1,
    datasets: datasets1,
  };

  // Tooltip
  const titleTooltip = ctx => {
    let sum = ['Sum: 77'];
    MONTHS.forEach(month => {
      sum.push(month);
    });    
    return sum;
  }

  var randomScalingFactor = function() {
    return (Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1.0 : 1.0) * Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  };

  var line1 = [randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor()];

  myChart = new Chart(chartId, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        x: {
          barPercentage: 1.6,
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
            color: 'rgba(225,78,202,0.1)',
            zeroLineColor: "transparent",
          },
          ticks: {
            padding: 0,
            fontColor: "#9a9a9a"
          },
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Week Of'
          }
        },
        y: {
          barPercentage: 1.6,
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
            color: 'rgba(225,78,202,0.1)',
            zeroLineColor: "transparent",
          },
          ticks: {
            padding: 0,
            fontColor: "#9a9a9a"
          },
          stacked: false,
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Count'
          }
        }
      },
      plugins: {
        tooltip: {
          //yAlign: 'bottom',
          callbacks: {
            title: titleTooltip,
            label: ctx => ctx.label + ': ' + ctx.parsed.y
          }
        }
      }
    }

  });

  return myChart;

}

trendsChart(['created', 'tested', 'reviewed', 'approved'], [{ data: [1, 5, 3, 2]}], 'myChart');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.8.0/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help.  I have six data points on each plot.  I have six months in an array.
Let's say we have two arrays: MONTHS = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'] and INTEGERS = [3, 20, 7, 2, 13, 9].
Now, the six data points should have:
Point 1: Jan 3,
Point 2: Feb 20,
Point 3: Mar 7,
Point 4: Apr 2,
Point 5: May 13,
Point 6: Jun 9

Each point should have a month, followed by a number.